# Views counter suggestion

Tags: discussion, design, views

I just had this idea about the counter on each question that displays how many times it's been viewed.

Instead of saying like 143232 or 5932123 wouldn't it be nicer and more modernistic to instead display like 143.2K and 5.9M?

Comment: And what for? To make it less informative?

Comment: I find 143K and 5.9M *more* informative because I don't have to count digits to figure out which one is bigger.  The exact number can always be available on hover just like with abbreviated reputation.  Since this problem is only going to get worse going forward, this seems like a good idea to me.

Answer (score 11):

No, that doesn't seem like a good idea because none of the numbers on the question page are abbreviated.

> [image: no abbreviated numbers on question page]

Comment: Horray for UI consistency.

Comment: @ryanyuyu well it's not that consistent if you look at the reputation of the very user who posted this answer.

Comment: To be honest I did see that and there are a few other place where the K and M notation is used. However, my user card is not part of the question I could argue and it needs space to convey other important information. With that hint you have enough data to create a new request that works for both consistency and information density and clearity.